# angular 2 app response from Slim php is net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: rest, angular, slim

```
    Hi everyone,

    this is the code in slim php:

    $app->post('/checkSignIn', function () use ($app) {
        $params =  $app->request->post()['body'] ;

        if(!empty($params))
        {
           $jsonRequest = json_decode($params);
            //echo $jsonRequest->email;

            $delikatesDbConnect = new DelikatesDbConnect ('localhost', 'gontar_delikates', 'DgDgDg11', 'gontar_delikates');
            $id = $delikatesDbConnect->findUserIdByMail($jsonRequest->email);
            //echo $id;
            if ($id>0) // if $id exists fetch hashed password and email_verfied values
            {
                $hashed_password = $delikatesDbConnect->findPasswordById($id);
                $email_verified = $delikatesDbConnect->findEmailVerifiedById($id);



                if (password_verify($jsonRequest->password,$hashed_password) and ($email_verified))
                {
                    $arr = $delikatesDbConnect->json_user_details($id);
                    $jsonResponse = json_encode($arr);
                    $response = new HttpResponse($jsonResponse,202);
                    return $response;
                }
                else
                {
                    return '';
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return '';
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return '';
        }
    })->name('register'); 

this is the request code in typscript ng2:

sendUserAndPass(userDetails:JSON)
  {
    const body = JSON.stringify(userDetails);
    console.log(body);
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    this.http.post("http://www.delikates.co.il/backend/checkSignIn", body, {headers: headers})
        .subscribe((data:Response)=>console.log(data));
  }
```

Why do i get in chrome console err message like that :
OPTIONS http://www.delikates.co.il/backend/checkSignIn net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0  for URL: null

Uncaught Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers…}

Comment: when i check via simple html form, the php program enters the important if statement : if (password_verify($jsonRequest->password,$hashed_password) and ($email_verified))
                {
                    $arr = $delikatesDbConnect->json_user_details($id);
                    $jsonResponse = json_encode($arr);
                    $response = new HttpResponse($jsonResponse,202);
                    return $response;
                }

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue with how you are handling the response.  What is HttpResponse?

A typical way of handling responses is to use the existing response object and write to that.

```
return $response->withJson($arr, 202);
```

https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html#returning-json

Comment: thanx my friend, isn't the problem much further in the program, where $response is ? . i eventully did retrieve from $params what i wanted to retrieve.

Comment: Anyway, i replaced the command with the command you suggested, but it didn't work.

Comment: the problem is here :if (password_verify($jsonRequest->password,$hashed_password) and ($email_verified))
            {
               // echo "good";
                $arr = $delikatesDbConnect->json_user_details($id);
                $jsonResponse = json_encode($arr);
                $response = new HttpResponse($jsonResponse,202);
                return $response;
            }

Comment: Sorry I misread the question.  I'll delete.
Are you using Slim 2 or Slim 3?

Comment: how can i learn which version is my slim? I opened up LICENSE file which is on my server among all other files, but version was not specified there

Comment: opyright (c) 2012 Josh Lockhart - this was the first line in the LISENCE file

Comment: If you're using composer, you can check your composer.json

    `"require": {
        "slim/slim": "3.*",
    }`

Comment: I also noticed that my README.md explicitly mentions slim 3 and the LICENSE.md says Copyright (c) 2011-2016 Josh Lockhart.  

So my guess is that you are using Slim 2